# How to watch digital TV (ISDB-T) on ubuntu?

Tags: tv, dvb

I have an ISDB-T USB receiver. On VLC I can plug it in and if I select DVB-T I can scan the bands but no channels are found. Is there a specific option for ISDB-T?

Comment: Is this connected to a properly installed home TV antenna?  DVB-T doesn't work with portable or table-top antennas (despite most of these adapters bundling one)

Comment: @thomasrutter no because the connector is different. How should I connect?

Comment: @thomasrutter I think it works because no one complained about the built in antenna. I thought it was a problem with linux itself, despite it being recognized properly and even responding to scans

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I partially agree with the "doesn't work" statement above. But it's true for most areas. They may work if close enough to a transmitter. And no, not a Linux problem.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia so the DVB-T option is the right one? The scanning really means it is scanning the brazillian range of tv channels?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I'm not sure about that. DVB-T is a different standard, used in Europe and most of the world. Brazil uses ISDB-T. Tuners aren't compatible/interchangeable. What I said above is my experience in Spain and what I read in blogs and forums here. I extrapolated for all different DTV standards which, I believe, behave the same way regardless of the different standards.